# PHP Syntax has to be off

Tags: php, html, hyperlink

So I have this code to name individual comments.

```
echo '<div class="leftpart"><a name="comment_'.$row["num"].'" ></a>';
```

The link that shows up like this...

```
?id=28#comment_34 /><a name=
```

What's up with the `/><a name=` ??

Should I show more code?

Comment: What about the `href` of the link?

Comment: Your right. I was missing a quote. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do you know what is there in $row["num"] exactly?

Maybe htmlspecialchars is required...

```
echo '<div class="leftpart"><a name="comment_'.htmlspecialchars($row["num"]).'" ></a>';
```